# Error updating Custom Teams App - ID in manifest doesn't match installed

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have created a 'Hello World' Teams app following the Microsoft getting started guide. This seemed to work as expected and I was able to add the application to my app catalog in the Teams client.

However, I am having problems updating the application without deleting and re-adding it.

For example:

1. Go to Teams App Studio -> Manifest Editor
2. Select the Hello World app
3. Change only the version number (e.g. 1.0.0 to 1.0.1)
4. Go to Test and Distribute and download the package.
5. Go to Apps and click the '...' button next to the installed Hello World 1.0.0 application.
6. Select Update and choose the package zip downloaded in step 4.

At this point, I get an error: The id in the manifest doesn't match with the app being updated.

Comparing the manifest.json file between the 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 app, the only thing that is different is the "version" field. Everything else, especially the "id" value is identical. I get the same problem when I manually alter the application version in the manifest.json and attempt to update the app. This happens with any custom app I've uploaded.

Any idea why I am not able to update an installed application? Am I missing something and these steps are just not valid?

Comment: is the app installed in your personal context already? Perhaps you installed it from App Studio previously (you can do that directly, without needing to download/upload). Also, are you installing to a personal context, or something else (e.g. a Team)?

Comment: If installed from App studio, you can click edit and change the version leaving the AppId same, and re- install again.

If you have uploaded the package through store, then you can click on the update and re-upload the package with updated version.

Comment: Also could you check once again with AppId is it same while updating as well.